# permission denied for relation schema_migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error when I run `rake db:migrate`:

```
permission denied for relation schema_migrations
```

This is what I have in my database.yml file:

```
development:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: enpoweredapp_development
 pool: 5
 username: enpowered
 password: enpowered
 host: localhost
```

Comment: Check if your `enpowered` user has all required privileges in your Postgres DB.

Comment: I got it to work. I just changed my username to the name listed ad the owner of the database.

Comment: you can post it as an answer than, please

Comment: Have the same issue. How do you find this username?

Comment: I did this and my postgres keeps on giving this same error. Could you please take a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424654/postgres-permission-denied-for-relation-schema-migrations)